# oracle forms 10g, connecting multiple forms using buttons

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

How to create a login form which check for password and then displays another main form from which I can access all the forms by click on ?

I have tried with

```
declare v_path varchar2(50);
begin
open_from(v_path);
end;
```

Button cannot know about this method.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

May be because the spelling mistake of "open_from".
Alternatively it can be done by :

```
declare v_path varchar2(50);
begin
  v_path := 'PATH TO YOUR NEW FORM .fmx';
  CALL_FORM(v_path,HIDE,DO_REPLACE);
end;
```